# Haskell function that executes differently depending on type of variable

Tags: haskell, polymorphism

To be more specific, suppose I have some data constructor

```
data Foo = ... deriving Eq
```

And the following silly function

```
f :: Eq a => a -> Bool
```

In cases where the variable *a* is actually of type *Foo*, I want *f* to output *True*. In all other cases (i.e. for all other instances of Eq), I want *f* to output *False*.

At first I thought maybe I could define a new type class for this purpose

```
class IsFoo a where
    isFoo :: a -> Bool
```

While it's easy to write an instance of *IsFoo* for *Foo*, obviously I don't want to do this for all types that are instances of Eq.

When answering, you can assume that Foo has A LOT of constructors and that I don't want to pattern match on all of them. I also don't want to use *Data.Typeable* (I've read that it's bad style). Is there a way to accomplish what I want in an elegant and natural (w.r.t. Haskell) way?

Comment: What do you *really* want to achieve?

Comment: This inherently breaks parametricity. Because of this, the type should reflect this in a clear way. Using `Data.Typeable` would do that. I concur on the fact that `Data.Typeable` is bad style, but this is because it allows to break parametricity, which is exactly what you require. Finding another way to do that without `Data.Typeable` would not make things better.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You shouldn't need to do this in my opinion. This seems like a serious XY problem to me, since Haskell's type system should generally do this stuff for you.

---

But nonetheless, it is possible. The easiest way to achieve this is indeed to use typeclasses:

```
data Foo = A | B | C | D | ... | Z deriving Eq

class IsFoo a where
  isFoo :: a -> Bool

instance IsFoo Foo where
  isFoo = const True

instance IsFoo x where
  isFoo = const False
```

Using the [`FlexibleInstances`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/FlexibleInstances) extension, you save yourself some work by simply returning `True` when given an argument of type `Foo`, which is specified in the instance for type `Foo` and `False` when calling `isFoo` with a variable of any other type. Note that you also have to use the extension [`OverlappingInstances`](https://ghc.haskell.org/trac/haskell-prime/wiki/OverlappingInstances), otherwise a runtime error will occur calling `isFoo` with an argument of type `Foo` because the program will not know which instance to use. To enable these extensions, simply include

```
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleInstances, OverlappingInstances #-}
```

at the top of your source file.

Still: I strongly suggest trying a different approach to your problem because in general you do not have to deal with such "low-level" typing stuff.

Comment: I completely agree on the last strong suggestion. `OvelappingInstances` is rather tricky, if not evil, and it's better to avoid it as much as possible.

Answer (score 5):

If this is really what you want to do, I'd suggest you to use `Data.Typeable`, because it's suited exactly for this purpose:

```
import Data.Maybe (isJust)
import Data.Typeable

isFoo :: (Typeable a) => a -> Bool
isFoo x = isJust (cast x :: Maybe Foo)
```

The question of bad style isn't about using a particular library like `Data.Typeable`. It's about not using Haskell's type system properly, in particular treating it like a dynamic OO language. If you need to determine if some generic type is `Foo` or is not, then you somewhere forgot the type information. But in Haskell, you always have this at compile time, so there shouldn't be the need of determining it dynamically.

Perhaps explain what you want to achieve, it's likely that there is a more idiomatic way how to do that.